# What makes MySQL Time functions preferred over PHP handling time?

Tags: php, mysql, database, time, format

As for college, I'm reading `PHP & MySQL for Dynamic Web Sites 4th Edition`.

In my readings there is a note:

`In your Web Applications, you should almost always use MySQL functions to format any dates coming from the database (as opposed to formatting the dates within PHP after retrieving them from the database).`

I know that MySQL time functions are very flexible. The book fails to elaborate and my instructor fails to know why exactly it's recommended. Is it simply for the flexibility, or is there performance gains from this as well?

Comment: Avoid an unnecessary roundtrip maybe?(Performance)

Comment: Simple sayed: If you are using php the date as string must be first anlaysed and then reformated. So little overhead plus extra function calls. But on the other side: Most PHP Dev are not the master of MYSQL, so they prefer the use of php date functions.  Finally it thing: Depends on the Application and can become micro-benchmarking. But what should prevent at all is the mix of both!

Comment: probably due to the mysql engine running at a lower level than php so your query for date_format() or whatever can run via an optimised pipeline internally so is faster with lower overhead.  running it via php needs to run through php engine first then compile down to run on the actual processor slightly more overhead although in reality these days it'd be almost un-traceable unless on multi-million row looping/sorting/parsing.

Comment: Assuming you've put the date into MySQL sensibly in the first place you've got a little less confusion when it comes to timezones... you *know* your `DATE` in MySQL is going to be UTC whereas, with PHP, you could be juggling timezones.

Comment: I would say the opposite is true!!! Let javascript handle the dates in whatever locale the end user prefers!!